# Sequelize: delete or update a table that is referenced using a foreign key in another table - can it be done?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I have 2 tables: one is called Products and one is called Orders. I want to se-seed the Products table with a new list of products, but the Orders table also references to Products.

My seed method was to delete all the Products and repopulate the table with the new list. The new list will ALWAYS have all the old products, plus new ones and occasionally some updates to the old ones, so there is no risk of any Orders being left without a Product to reference using the old foreign key.

However I'm getting an error: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: update or delete on table "products" violates foreign key constraint "orders_products_fkey" on table "orders".

I guess there may be other ways to update the list, but it is a big list of over 100,000 products and deleting all and reseeding is lightning fast. Perhaps I shouldn't have made an actual reference, though now the db is in production.

I appreciate any and all guidance and direction! Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: `...   deleting all and reseeding is lightning fast....` It is also terribly wrong. People have placed orders on the old products, and you are changing the definitions.

Comment: I've simplified my explanation, but re-seeding the products is by id and each is absolutely unique by the id (basically the database I'm using has its own inbuilt constraints). The only thing that changes is trivial information on each one, so actually this system would not be an issue. Though I realize the way I've done it is not optimal, it was a mistake. Would you have any suggestions on how I can fix the issue itself?